# how to find entity resides to which Module in crm

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I wanted to know how to find entity resides in which Module in crm. (progamatically)

Example: "Accounts" entity resides to which module ?

I need to develop a code which tells me "Accounts" entity resides in Sales/Service module!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Module" is a fancy business terminology you would find CRM Sales personnel or training materials use to segregate dynamics CRM core functionality into smaller functional chunks. CRM itself doesn't have a data structure for modules which hold a group of entities. [SiteMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334280.aspx) is used to group all logical entities under one umbrella (e.g. Sales which contains "Lead", "Opportunity" ...)

If all you want is to query which "module" your "Account" entity is grouped under, you could query your sitemap to get the "Area" and the [SubArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328498.aspx).

One caveat here, if your CRM administrator has grouped entities which aren't necessarily grouped under logical "modules" you are out of luck (e.g. Under Sales if "Email" was added), as site maps are often customized and seldom used the way they are shipped.